# How to get last midnight in Dart?

Tags: datetime, dart, flutter

I guess this is pretty common task in most languages, however it was not clear to me how to get this done in my Flutter app. How to retrieve DateTime object of the last midnight in Dart? Or potentially, any particular time today / tomorrow / yesterday?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This should do the same

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var lastMidnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

You can use this way to get different times of this day

```
var tomorrowNoon = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 12);

var yesterdaySixThirty = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 1, 6, 30);
```

Depending on what you want can absolute values be more safe because adding/subtracting `Duration` can result in surprises because of leap years and daylight saving time.

Answer (score 5):

Try this package [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy), uses the simplicity of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) syntax. See below

To get last midnight

```
var lastMidnight = Jiffy.now().subtract(days: 1).startOf(Unit.day);

print(lastMidnight.dateTime); // 2019-10-20 00:00:00.000
//or you can also format it
print(lastMidnight.yMMMMEEEEdjm); // Sunday, October 20, 2019 12:00 AM
```

Comment: I think this should just be `Jiffy.now().startOf(Unit.day)` to find the previous midnight...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Use this solution only if you are working with UTC (daylight saving times might mess it up), or rather use the accepted answer anyway.

---

The simplest solution I found so far:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final lastMidnight = now.subtract(Duration(
  hours: now.hour,
  minutes: now.minute,
  seconds: now.second,
  milliseconds: now.millisecond,
  microseconds: now.microsecond,
));
```

Then we can get any other time or day relative to today by subtracting or adding Duration, e.g.:

```
final tomorrowNoon = lastMidnight.add(Duration(days: 1, hours: 12));
final yesterdaySixThirty = lastMidnight
    .subtract(Duration(days: 1))
    .add(Duration(hours: 6, minutes: 30));
```

Note that DateTime is immutable and both methods (add, subtract) return a new object.

Comment: This solution can fail to hit midnight around daylight saving time changes. When we switch to daylight saving, there are 14 hours since midnigth at 1PM. This code *does* work if you are working with UTC dates, since there are no daylight saving in UTC.