# how do i get Device datetime in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can i get my device date and time in flutter? given this example: assuming my device date and time is set to 2020-01-01 time 5:50 PM and the actual date is 2020-09-03 time 3:00 PM. how do i get the device time and date not the actual time and date on flutter. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696478/datetime-flutter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get last midnight in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250431/how-to-get-last-midnight-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the DateTime class

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime().now();
```

Or, if you want it as a string

```
dateTime.toIso8601String();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default when **DateTime** object is encountered, it uses UTC time zone or in the local time zone of the current computer when the **object** is created.
If you want to get **true time** instead of computer time then use **true_time 0.1.0** package of dart