# How to find kernal time of real device using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, time, startup, mobile-application

Please, I want to find the kernel time of my application and I want to test it on a real device. Is there any way to find it by using flutter?

Also, I use this command: flutter run --trace-startup --profile. It is shown in the console, but I want it to show in the UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725387/how-do-i-get-device-datetime-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin   [ntp: ^2.0.0](https://%20https://pub.dev/packages/ntp)

```
 DateTime startDate = await NTP.now();
 print('NTP DateTime: ${startDate}');
```

Comment: thank you dear. If I want to know how long it takes for my app to become visible to the user, will it work with it or not?

Comment: It won't take long time to visible , It'll visible in seconds

Comment: If this helps to u accept the answer dear

Comment: Yes, I know it won't take a long time, but in my MSc research, I tried to find the user time and kernal time of several mobile phones. So, I need it to find the package.

Comment: Oh for M.Sc research ? Where do u from ?